# Passing an index macro to compiled modules

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++

I compile my project using a makefile with an expression in the style of
`g++ -c a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp`
Is there any easy way to define a macro that will increment every file? (e.g. a 0, b 1, c 2)

Needless to say, but project consists of countless files and the number changes, so hardcoding anything is out of the question.

Comment: What do you mean by 'increment every file'? Do you need a counter, that counts the files you pass, or a way to start from 'a.cpp' and automatically end in, say, 'z.cpp', or something else?

Comment: Also, the command `g++ a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp` is not a valid compiler command.  If you want help please be specific: what do you _REALLY_ run?  If you really do invoke a single compiler invocation with all your source files, then nothing make will do can help you to count them because make invokes one command to build them all; how can it count anything?

Comment: Well I actually run g++ -C (files), which compiles the source files but doesn't link them. The point is to have an integer macro which is uniqe for each object file.

Comment: Must this macro work for *any* filename you pass to it, or can it be restricted to a list of filenames?

Comment: It must work for any list of filenames. Though I solved with some makefile dark magic

Comment: If you're satisfied with your solution, post it as an Answer; if not, I have a solution (also dark).

Comment: I am currently away from my work computer, and cannot reach the code. I broke the make rule for compiling to two separate rules, 1 for compiling a single file and one for linking, and I stored the index in a file on the file system.

Comment: *Dude!* We don't have to resort to that. Just to be clear, you want a way to take an arbitrary list of filenames and convert it into a list of numbers. Each number should be a function of the corresponding filename (so that if a filename appears in two lists, it will be converted to the same number) and the numbers should not collide (that is, two different filenames should not be assigned the same number). For example, {a.cpp bar.o charlie.z} => {433 86743 55901} and {foo.x a.cpp dummy} => {11777 433 45837}. Is that right?

Comment: Technically, yes, but I'd like it to be an incrementing integer starting from zero, because later I'm going to generate something out of the object file and I'd like it to be an index

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74037/discussion-between-beta-and-gilad-naaman).

Answer (score 0):

It's not overly clear what you're trying to do, but it should be possible to substitute a bash command to do this:

```
%.c: 
    @#do nothing

all:  depA.c depB.c depC.c
    echo `i=0; for f in $^; do echo $$f; echo $$i; i=$$((i+1)); done`
```

would output

```
echo `i=0; for f in depA.c depB.c depC.c; do echo $f; echo $i; i=$((i+1)); done`
depA.c 0 depB.c 1 depC.c 2
```

You can of course substitute the `$^` with another variable if you're working off a variable list.

John